# When hosted on github.io, doesn't make fetch() requests

Tags: html, github, fetch, github-pages

when I localhost my website, everything works, requests come through, info displays but when I host it on github.io or replit.com, no requests come through, why?

Github.io site:
https://asxlvm.github.io/#/settings

Github repo for the page:
https://github.com/asxlvm/asxlvm.github.io/docs

When I localhost;

Site on local

[image]

API Responses for the local requests

[image]

When I host on github.io;

[image: Screenshot of the Site on github.io]

Comment: Open up your developer console and you will see the problem:
`Access to fetch at 'https://thingproxy.freeboard.io/fetch/https://dogehousebot.asylumekk.repl.co/api/botinfo' from origin 'https://asxlvm.github.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource....` Long story short, you need to make sure your backend puts the URL of your Origin(frontend) in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. You can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Oh, okay, and how may I do that? Just add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to my header in the fetch?

Comment: I'm new to js so I'm a dummy :D